# f2py compiling f77 program with exposed variables

Tags: python, fortran, fortran77, f2py

I was trying to compile a legacy code written in f77 using f2py.
The snippet of the code is shown below to demonstrate the issue I am facing.

```
      PROGRAM TEST
      IMPLICIT REAL*8(A-H,O-Z)
      CHARACTER IFILE*30, TITLE(8)*10
      DIMENSION XINT(100), X(200), Y(200), W(200)
      COMMON /HLM/ DUMMX(2000)
      COMMON /SMY/ DUMMY(2130)
      COMMON /BLK1/ PI,PI2,RAD,CONS
      END PROGRAM TEST
```

when I compile this using:

```
f2py -c test.f -m test
```

However when I load this module, I cannot see or access the arrays xint, x, y and w
Only the common block variables are avaialble.

```
Python 3.10.4 (main, Apr  2 2022, 09:04:19) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> dir(test)
['__doc__', '__f2py_numpy_version__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_test_error', 'hlm']
>>> dir(test.hlm)
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'dummx']
>>>
```

What would be the correct way to declare these variables such that they will be accessible in python ?

Thanks.